# updatable join view

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am currently trying updatable_join_view using hr scheme(EMP, DEPT Table).

I tried to join to tables named as emp and dept. And I also made view as like this.

```
create or replace view v4
as
select e.empno, e.ename, d.dname, d.loc
from emp e, dept d
where e.deptno = d.deptno;
```

So, I made view above like that, as join view, there is only one constraint on e.empno column as **not null**.

After this, if I try under this code,

```
select *
from user_updatable_columns
where table_name = 'V4';
```

I could see like this

```
OWNER      TABLE_NAME COLUMN_NAM UPDATA INSERT DELETA
---------- ---------- ---------- ------ ------ ------
ACE24      V4         EMPNO      NO     NO     NO
ACE24      V4         ENAME      NO     NO     NO
ACE24      V4         DNAME      NO     NO     NO
ACE24      V4         LOC        NO     NO     NO
```

And to make as updatable join view, I added primary key constraint on e.empno so the key could be preserved.

```
alter table emp
add constraint empno_pk primary key(empno);
```

So, I expected that I could update or insert or delete on dept table's dname, loc column. But I still can find out this result.

```
OWNER      TABLE_NAME COLUMN_NAM UPDATA INSERT DELETA
---------- ---------- ---------- ------ ------ ------
ACE24      V4         EMPNO      NO     NO     NO
ACE24      V4         ENAME      NO     NO     NO
ACE24      V4         DNAME      NO     NO     NO
ACE24      V4         LOC        NO     NO     NO
```

I wanna know what is the problem.

Comment: Complex views cannot be updated. You need to use `instead of trigger` to do so.

Comment: thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unique constraint needs to be on the parent, so that the database knows the lookup won't create duplicates.

```
alter table dept add constraint dept_pk primary key (deptno);

alter view v4 compile;
```

Then I get:

```
OWNER         TABLE_NAME    COLUMN_NAME   UPDATABLE INSERTABLE DELETABLE
------------- ------------- ------------- --------- ---------- ---------
DSL_OWNER_82  V4            EMPNO         YES       YES        YES
DSL_OWNER_82  V4            ENAME         YES       YES        YES
DSL_OWNER_82  V4            DNAME         NO        NO         NO
DSL_OWNER_82  V4            LOC           NO        NO         NO
```

Comment: Glad it helped, but "thank you" comments are discouraged on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers